# Which programming environments or APIs are available for the LEGO BOOST?

Tags: programming, electronics, boost

Over the holidays I tried the following Python library:
https://github.com/undera/pylgbst but I couldn't get it to work.
Then again my knowledge of Python is very limited.

I'm more experienced with C++ or C#, is anything available for those languages?

As a general question, do you know of any programming environments or API's that can control the LEGO move hub and its peripherals from the LEGO BOOST set?

Answer (score 6):

[Boost](https://rebrickable.com/sets/17101-1/creative-toolbox/) and the other Powered Up components (the new City [trains](https://rebrickable.com/sets/60197-1/passenger-train/), the [app-controlled batmobile](https://rebrickable.com/sets/76112-1/app-controlled-batmobile/), and [WeDo 2.0](https://rebrickable.com/sets/45300-1/wedo-core-set/)) are controlled via Bluetooth. Any environment that can send bluetooth commands can be used to control these components.

There is a [github page](https://github.com/JorgePe/BOOSTreveng) which documents some of the reverse-engineering that has been done and it links to several third-party Boost/PoweredUp programming libraries. I've used [movehub](https://github.com/hobbyquaker/node-movehub), but there is another node.js library called [node-poweredup](https://github.com/nathankellenicki/node-poweredup) which looks more complete.

[Lego themselves have documented part of the BLE wireless protocol on github](https://github.com/LEGO/lego-ble-wireless-protocol-docs) as well.

Answer (score 3):

Not C but you might take a look at https://github.com/JorgePe/pyb00st

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer C#, there a new lib on the block: [SharpBrick.PoweredUp](https://github.com/sharpbrick/powered-up). While the Boost hub and motors are missing, the protocol is implemented. Your use case should be two minor contributions away.

Full Disclaimer: I maintain the library. I do not have Boost Hardware but the protocol officially supports Boost Hub. Just some enums and types are missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try our just released WeDo 2.0 Framework that should suppot Boost partially (full support will be added soon). It is open source and free for education (written in C#). You can find it by this link: https://github.com/btframework/WeDo